# Wordpress admin not accessible

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-admin

My wordpress site was working perfectly all right for last 2 years. Suddenly yesterday it started saying "Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page." when I try to access wp-admin.

I have not changed anything yesterday, the only change which has happened is increase in traffic, since the site is getting 4x traffic.

I have tried disabling all the plugins, checked user details in the database everything appears intact. Tried many commonly suggestions for this problem but still the issue persists.

One observation is some of the plugins are not working apart from access issues to the wp-admin. 15 days back I had installed certificates and moved to HTTPS can, but had no issues due to the move.

Can anyone suggest something, please?

Comment: how did you disable all the plugins?

Comment: I have access to the server and renaming plugin folder I disabled them all.

Comment: Why -ve votes guys, this is a genuine questions and critical for thousands of the wordpress users.

Comment: Well 80% of the reported issues here are not coding related, issues with the software can be anything not always coding related and people need help on everything.

Comment: may be because the reported issue cannot be reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

Might be an issue with unix permissions, if your is a linux server (you did not specify anything about your system).

Usually, if you have:

```
/var/www/mywordpress
```

with `drwxrwxr-x` then the website is full open to anybody.

Else, if the permissions are `dr-x------` you may get the error

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /mywordpress/ on this server.
```

But I don't think someone or you, changed permissions on the folder. Still, better if you have a look onto it

EDIT:
This link might be of help:
[codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions)

Comment: Hi Nihvel, mine is a unix/ubuntu server and the file permissions too are exactly same as that of my other wordpress instance. Anyway thanks for the answer, I will try to explore more on this lines too